# Does the flux on the surface changes if the origin changes?

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute the flux integral with vector field,
$\vec F(x,y,z)= <2x,y,3z>$
and a sphere of radius 36 centered at the point $(1,2,-1)$

so what I did was I used divergence theorem which is

$\int\int \vec F \cdot \vec n dS = \int \int \int (div \vec F) dV$

I used the right hand side and so

$\int \int \int 6dV$

From here I can see the answer is 6*(volume of sphere), and hence my answer doesn't change even if the origin of sphere is different. So my question is, does the flux integral answer changes when the origin of sphere change?(assuming volume does not change)

Answer (score 1):

Since the divergence of the field $\vec{F}$ is constant, the given integral doesn't depend on the origin of the sphere. Moreover, the surface mustn't even be sphere shaped, as long as it encloses the same volume.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought of that. It seems logical to me that at different points in the field, the flux would be different. I guess I'm wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

I read about flux in my electostatics class . So I may be wrong but :-

Consider flow of a liquid with velocity **v**, through a small
flat surface **dS**, in a direction normal to the surface. The
rate of flow of liquid is given by the volume crossing the
area per unit time **v . dS** and represents the flux of liquid
flowing across the plane.

Now for a sphere  it doesn't matter where you place it , the Surface Area remains same and as it is a sphere , changing the angle doesn't make a difference. So flux remains the same.